# Entity Framework storing arrays of data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, data-modeling

I've started playing around with using Entity Framework Code-First because it looks like a nice way to get a database up and running quickly. I'm coming from a PostgreSQL background, which has support for array types in tables, for example `time[]`. My question is two-fold; does SQL Server support array types, and if so, how can I use them in EF? If they're not supported, what is an alternative way to represent this data?

```
table Venue
    openhours time[]
```

**Edit:** The array above is intended to store different times for each day of the week- a venue might have different opening hours on different weekends to weekdays, for example.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not supported, you need to store your `openhours` in a separate table (`VenueOpenhours`) with a foreign key to the `Venue` table.

Comment: I suspected this would be the solution, it just looks ugly to join 7 rows to get a single venue's opening hours.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't support array types. Extrapolating from your example schema, I think an equivalent EF POCO would be the following:

```
public class Venue
{
   public int VenueId { get; set; }
   public DateTime OpenHour { get; set; }
   public DateTime CloseHour { get; set; }
}
```

Finding whether the `Venue` was open at a given time would just require a range query, `Venue.Where(a => a.OpenHour <= time && a.CloseHour >= time)`. Of course, this is a very simplistic example. Most likely you'd want to store the Venue hours in another table. But I hope this may be able to move you in the right direction.